# Customize minimum payout on ethermine

Tags: cpp-ethereum, mining-pools, balances, genoil

On the homepage of eterhmine it says that one of their features is "Customizable minimum payment threshold (Standard: 1 Ether, Minimum: 0.05 Ether, Maximum: 10 Ether)" and yet everything else I'm reading about says it pays out after 1 ether.

I am new to mining and want to make sure I am doing this correctly (I'm showing ~50 MH/s so I think it's working alright, but I won't be happy until I see a non-zero ether amount in my balance!).

(1) Is there a way to change the minimum payout so that I can go from zero to non-zero on a shorter timeline?

(2) Is there any other way to see results sooner? Even if there is not a smaller payout, is there a way to see that I am X% of the way to my next ether or anything like that?

For what it's worth, I'm using Genoils miner and have followed their directions but tweaked it slightly for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find your address on etherminer by searching it in the top bar -> go to settings -> change minimum to 0.05 or whatever you want it to be, and provide your public IP as proof it is you (just google my ip and it will tell you what it is)